# iOS-> AWS best practices

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

When building an app using iOS and AWS, would you recommended using SSL to shuttle data back and forth from user to server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, why not? Given how more and more countries (and even ISPs acting independently) are heading in that direction it's more important than ever to secure communications from prying eyes.

Granted, encryption does consume more CPU power but for short transfers it shouldn't make a difference. How much data (in bytes) were you thinking of transferring between your iOS device and AWS?

Remember to check the certificate itself to ensure it's still valid and is a genuine Amazon cert and not an imposter.

Comment: was thinking for general server / dB hits